# Are function calls like read() , write() actual system calls in linux?

Tags: c++, c, linux

I have been writing programs in C/C++ that make use of the Linux API and make system calls like fork(),read(),write() etc. Now, I am beginning to wonder if these library functions are actually system calls, or are they some kind of wrapper functions.

What really happens when a program makes a call to write() ? 
How does this function interact with the kernel ?
If this is a wrapper then why do we need it ?

Comment: How about reading assenbly code that your compiler emits or using a debugger to trace what your program does?

Comment: A quick way to find out what calls are simple system call wrappers is usually to use `man`. Section 2 contains system calls so that `man 2 read` shows up is an indication that read indeed is a wrapped system call.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All such functions are real userspace functions in `libc.so` that your binary is linked against. But most of them are just tiny wrappers for syscalls which are the interface between the userspace and the kernel (see also `syscall(2)`).

Note that functions that are purely userspace (like `fmod(3)`) or do some things in userspace in addition to calling the kernel (like `execl(3)`) have their manpages in the section 3 while functions that just call the kernel (like `read(2)`) have them in the section 2.

Comment: It's the other way round. Functions that are pure wrappers are in section 2. Section 3 is or the rest. See e.g. execl(3) and execve(2).

Comment: @a3f Thats what he said. System call wrappers in section 2, pure user-space function in section 3.

Comment: @EJP Someone might be lead to believe that entries in section 3 do not call the kernel. As else they would have to be in section 2, because the answer currently states "functions that call the kernel have them in section 2".

Comment: @a3f You will always need a syscall to perform I/O from userspace. But functions in section 3 does not need to involve a syscall (sprintf variants). The relation is (2) => syscall but not the other way around.

Comment: @user877329 That's what I said.

Comment: @wRAR As you said, functions like fork() are actually wrappers for syscalls. Isn't syscall a userspace function too? And why use a wrapper function when you can make syscalls ? Also, I would like to know what happens when the wrapper makes syscalls - Does the syscall function set the registers and give an Interrupt signal to the kernel or are there some intermediate steps ?

Comment: @TUSHARPODDAR see `syscall(2)` for the details about invoking the kernel. Using a wrapper function is cleaner, easier, more portable etc. while using the syscall directly doesn't provide any benefits. Most wrappers just call the kernel and then handle errors, some of them may also convert arguments to a different form etc. You may want to consult glibc sources for more details.

Answer (score 1):

using this simple code :

```
int main()
{
    int f = open("/tmp/test.txt", O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0666);
    write(f, "hello world", 11);
    close(f);

    return 0;
}
```

you can use `strace` to find system calls used in the binary file :

```
gcc test.c -o test
strace ./test
```

the result is something like this :

```
.
.
.
open("/tmp/test.txt", O_RDWR|O_CREAT, 0666) = 3
write(3, "hello world", 11)             = 11
close(3)                                = 0
exit_group(0)                           = ?
```

as for `fork()`, it's actually a wrapper around `clone()` system call